# Use of possessive apostrophe for 2 people who have the same attitude

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

'No uncertainty exists about Jim and Bob's attitude to Stan - they despised him.'

- or -

'No uncertainty exists about Jim's and Bob's attitude to Stan - they despised him.'

I have seen questions related to two people sharing a wedding or a house but what if two people each have an attitude and it's the same?

Answer (score 1):

Either

> No uncertainty exists about Jim and Bob's attitude to Stan - they despised him.

or

> No uncertainty exists about Jim's and Bob's attitudes to Stan - they despised him.

are fine.

The first one is valid because it is a single attitude (against Sam) held by more than one person.

The second one does not carry such an implication.

Answer (score -2):

I would word it as follows: 
'No uncertainty exists about Jim's and Bob's attitudes to Stan - they despised him.'

Because you have two objects in the subject, you should use the plural for attitude as well.

Or I would rephrase the item something like, "Because Jim and Bob despise him, there is no uncertainty about their attitudes."

Comment: When I asked a software question, some people would respond, "why do you want to do it that way? Why don't you do it this way instead?" Those are frustrating responses that don't answer the question at hand. I what to know how to do it this way, so don't brush the situation away. When you sit for a Maths exam, where a question specifically asks for an algebraic method of solving, you don't usually rewrite the question by insisting on giving the easier inductive solution.

Comment: He asked "I have seen questions related to two people sharing a wedding or a house but what if two people each have an attitude and it's the same?"

So you are saying that the first statement where the answer is located did not answer the question?  

It certainly looks like he wants to know how it would look if "two people each have an attitude and it's the same".  Is that not apparent in the answer?